# Automatically download and save tableau packaged workbook offline after refresh

Tags: automation, tableau-api, build-automation, tableau-desktop

I have a workbook on Tableau Server, which is scheduled to refresh daily.  Most users subscribe to a view, which they receive automatically on email once the workbook is refreshed.  However, some users do not have access to Tableau Server, only Tableau Reader.  For these users I am required to download the packaged workbook after it has been refreshed and save it offline everyday.  Does anyone know how this process can be automated, so that after the workbook is refreshed on Tableau Server it will download and save to the offline location?  Or any other solutions for those with only Tableau Reader, so that they can access the workbook without manual intervention each day?

I have tried searching the Tableau website for help, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use any tool similar to Airflow. Trigger workbook refresh from it and download the file in the specified location. You can use [Tableau Server Client](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooks) for this.

It's not an easy fix though. Requires a bit of development work.